# Matching both conditions with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match the input string by both given conditions. For example, if I give `'000011001000'` as input and want to match it by `'1001'` and `'0110'` then what would the regex I need look like?

I tried different combinations, but couldn't find the correct one. The closest I got was using

```
re.match("(1001.*0110)+?")
```

but that one doesn't work when input is for example `'0001100100'`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to match `'1001'` **or** `'0110'`? What if they overlap? What is the output you're expecting?

Comment: I want to match them both. Output should be 'True' or 'False'. So with '0110000' it would be False, but with '0001100100' it would be True.

Comment: So you only want a match if both `'1001'` and `'0110'` are in the string, potentially overlapping? Why not just `if '1001' in s and '0110' in s:`, rather than trying to do it with regex?

Comment: Normally I would, but right now I can't, because I have an assignment where I have to use regex only...

Comment: Can't see any harm in asking people for help. This is only 1 of the 15 exercises. ;)

Comment: Then do the other 14 and come back to this one later.

Comment: Is overlapping a concern?

Comment: Yes, it has to return 'True' when overlapping, but right now it doesn't for obvious reasons.

Comment: Ok, easiest way to handle overlapping is to use a construct that doesn't advance the current regex "pointer" during the scan. That being lookaheads....but I guess that answer beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern makes use of *"look-arounds"* which you should learn about for regex.

```
(?=[01]*1001[01]*)(?=[01]*0110[01]*)[01]+
```

in response to the comments:

look-arounds in regex are a simple way of checking the match for specific conditions. what it essentially does is stop the current match cursor when it hits the `(?=` (there are also others suchs as `?!, ?<=, and ?<!`) token and reads the next characters using the pattern inside of the lookaround statement. if that statement is not fulfilled then the match fails. if it does, then the original cursor then keeps matching. imagine it being a probe that goes ahead of an explorer to check the environment ahead.

if you want more reference, [rexegg](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) is probably my favourite site for learning regex syntax and nifty tricks.

Comment: *"you should be doing your own homework. but I am bored"* - this is worse than the people who answer not realising it's not OK, at least they have the excuse that they didn't know...

Comment: I don't see where in the rules it says "no answering user's homework questions."  It's not on the community to enforce the policies of a school, nor do we have to care.  There's a meta with a popular opinion that basically says ["don't be lazy when asking or answering"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  The asker *could* just pretend it's not homework, so what does it matter as long as the question is decently asked?

Comment: @tristan You are correct about homework questions being allowed and encouraged. However, one point to note from that meta link is "Providing an answer that doesn't help a student learn is not in the student's own best interest. Therefore you might choose to treat homework questions differently than other questions." :) jon's rigid stance on "no homework questions" is invalid, however that doesn't mean R Nar's answer is as good as it could be.

Comment: i could add documentation or explanation of look-arounds if thats what you are saying....

Comment: Yeah that would be a good start. It would help students learn *why* this approach works and how you came to the solution.

Comment: I have to explain my code to a teacher anyway, so I HAVE to know what it does. In my case, his answer was good since I can't use it without knowing what it does. So thanks again, R Nar.